# Making a copy of a BookOrder within BookOrder

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a copy of a BookOrder that I've already created, however, it isn't creating properly. So far, I have this.

```
public class BookOrder
{
    private String author;      
    private String title;
    private int quantity;
    private double costPerBook;
    private String orderDate;
    private double weight;
    private char type;      //R,O,F,U,N

    public BookOrder (String author, String title)
    {
    }

    public BookOrder(String author, String title, int quantity, double costPerBook, String orderDate, double weight, char type)
    {
        this.author= author;
        this.title= title;
        this.quantity= quantity;
        this.costPerBook= costPerBook;
        this.orderDate= orderDate;
        this.weight= weight;
        this.type=type;
    }

    public BookOrder(BookOrder bookOrder)
    {
    }
```

However, when I try to copy this here:

```
public class TestBookOrder
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        Utility.myInfo("11/5,2013", "Project4");
        Utility.pressEnterToContinue();
        Utility.clearScreen();

        BookOrder BookOrder1 = new BookOrder("Jonathan", "Book1", 12, 6.75, "11/5/2013", 8.75, 'r');
        System.out.print(""+ BookOrder1.invoice());

        BookOrder copyA = new BookOrder(BookOrder1);

        BookOrder copyB= new BookOrder(BookOrder1);

        copyB.adjustQuantity(-5);

        System.out.print("\n"+ copyB.invoice());
        System.out.print("\n"+ copyA.invoice());

    }
}
```

it just returns the invoice for copyA and copyB as null and 0. Anyone know what code needs to be within the copy method?

Comment: You've ignored the advice given to you in an answer to your similar question from 1 hour ago. Why?

Comment: you need to realize your `BookOrder(BookOrder bookOrder)` constructor. But your variables are ptivate, so I hope you have all getters (and setters) to o this!)

Comment: @AndrewEvt: he does as can be seen in his previous question on the same assignment.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19804825/bookorder-class-isnt-rendering-results-in-test oh, yep... But what is wrong?) why he asks twice??) Dear `Jon5001` read more about constructors, and how thay works. I think it will solve all your problems!

Answer (score 1):

To make this work, you need to change following code. This will create a new Object and will populate same with BookOrder value passed as input. Hope this answers your doubt.

```
public BookOrder(BookOrder bookOrder)
    {
    this.author= bookOrder.getAuthor();
    this.title= bookOrder.getTitle();
    this.quantity= bookOrder.getQuantity();
    this.costPerBook= bookOrder.getCostPerBook();
    this.orderDate= bookOrder.getOrderDate();
    this.weight= bookOrder.getWeight();
    this.type=bookOrder.getType();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the values of the parameter BookOrder into your current parameters.

e.g.,

```
class Foo {
  private int bar;

  public Foo(Foo foo) {
    this.bar = foo.bar;
    // same for other fields if they exist.
  }
}
```

Incidentally, you will want to fix this:

```
public BookOrder (String author, String title)
{
}
```

You're throwing out the parameters passed into this constructor, completely ignoring them.

Edit: this was already explained to you in a previous answer to a previous question on the same assignment!

Answer (score 0):

That's because you need to assign all the fields from the passed object to the current object, in the copy constructor.

```
public BookOrder(BookOrder bookOrder) {
    this.author = bookOrder.getAuthor(); // since they are private and thus you need getter to get the values
    this.title = bookOrder.getTitle();
    this.quantity = bookOrder.getQuantity();
    this.costPerBook = bookOrder.getCostPerBook();
    this.orderDate = bookOrder.getOrderDate();
    this.weight = bookOrder.getWeight();
    this.type =bookOrder.getType();
}
```